# Equality over intervals

Tags: real-analysis

If $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$. How to prove that $\,\,[a,  b]\subseteq \{(1-t)a+tb:t\in[0, 1]\}$?

I showed the inclusion $\,\,\{(1-t)a+tb:t\in[0, 1]\}\subseteq [a,  b]$ butneed help with the inclusion $\,\,[a,  b]\subseteq \{(1-t)a+tb:t\in[0, 1]\}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \in [a,b]$, then let $t = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Then $t \in [0,1]$ and $(1-t) a + tb = (1-\frac{x-a}{b-a}) a + \frac{x-a}{b-a} b = x$. Hence $x \in \{(1-t)a+tb | t\in[0, 1]\}$, and so $[a,b] \subset \{(1-t)a+tb | t\in[0, 1]\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how to figure out the trick that copper.hat uses to determine the inclusion, remember that we want to show for $x\in[a,b]$ that there is some $t\in[0,1]$ such that $x=(1-t)a+tb.$ Well, let's see if we can solve that equation for $t$ and show that it is in the interval $[0,1]$. $$x=(1-t)a+tb$$ $$x=a-ta+tb$$ $$x=a+t(b-a)$$ $$x-a=t(b-a)$$ Now, since $b>a$, then we can divide by $b-a$ to get $$\frac{x-a}{b-a}=t,$$ and all that's left is to show that $0\leq t\leq 1.$ Well, since $b-a>0$, then multiplying the inequality $0\leq t\leq 1$ by $b-a$ yields the **equivalent** inequality $$0\leq x-a\leq b-a.$$ Then adding $a$ yields the equivalent inequality $$a\leq x\leq b,$$ which is true by our choice of $x.$

P.S.: This isn't intended to "compete" with copper.hat's answer, but to supplement it. Feel free to upvote mine, but I recommend that you accept copper.hat's, unless you don't really understand it.